# Use of two nested select in query

Tags: php, sql

I am using phpmyadmin 127.0.0.1.

The following code shows error but I cannot find anything wrong

```
$sde=" select * from 
(select * from students1
WHERE 
((PartCode = '$s1' OR PartCode =CONCAT('D', '$s1')) AND     (ElectiveSubject1='$s11' OR ElectiveSubject2='$s11' OR ElectiveSubject3='$s11')) 
ORDER BY PartCode, AdmitCode, RollCode 
LIMIT ${'rr'.$rnn.'1b'}, ${'rr'.$rnn.'1'})  
LIMIT $qa1, $qa2
";

$rde2=mysql_query($sde);
```

Please help me in finding the error. The error removes if we omit the portions outside the brakets ().

Comment: Your sub tables need an alias.   `SELECT * FROM (  ...) as tmpTable..`

Comment: Just for clarity: phpMyAdmin is a tool written in PHP for managing a MYSQL database. MySQL is the database, phpMyAdmin is just a tool to play with it.

Comment: [Please, don't use mysql_* functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)  in new code. They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Use [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific problem is that you are missing the table alias on the subquery.  I think it would be easier to write the second condition using `in`:

```
select s.* 
from (select s.*
      from students1 s
      where ((PartCode = '$s1' OR PartCode = CONCAT('D', '$s1')) AND  
             '$s11' in (ElectiveSubject1, ElectiveSubject2, ElectiveSubject3)
      order by PartCode, AdmitCode, RollCode 
      limit ${'rr'.$rnn.'1b'}, ${'rr'.$rnn.'1'}
     ) s
LIMIT $qa1, $qa2;
```

Next.  You need to move off the "mysql_" interface.  This is no longer supported.  When you switch to "mysqli_", then you can parameterize the column values.  This is a better approach.

Next.  You have three columns which only seem to differ by an integer at the end of their name.  That is a sign of poor database design.  In general, this means that your data model should have a junction table, with one row per student and elective subject.